# How do I create a Leaderboard using a text file in python?

Tags: python

I'm working on a quiz for my exam in computer science. I'm relatively new to the program, in the sense that I know all of the basics, but I am on the point where I want to expand my knowledge. One way I want to do this is by adding a Leaderboard system. The user gets a number of points, and then the program checks in a text file that has other high scores in it, and adds the user to it. It then prints out the leaderboard. This means that I'm going to have to use some sort of operations to determine whether the user's score is higher or lower than another score in the file, and then delete the score it is higher than and replace it. Any idea on how to do this? I'm completely stuck.

Comment: What code have you written thus far and where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Pseudeocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) and work through steps.

1. Get Score
2. Compare Score
3. Add Score

You have to think like a computer and break all the way down. At each step think about how do I tell the computer to do that. Once you have all that look at what you have done and remember DRY -> Don't Repeat Yourself. Your coding will go much faster.

Comment: all of my attempts thus far to do that have failed. Getting the score is fine. Comparing  it is hard as python keeps telling me that I cannot compare a string to an integer. Adding it is even harder as I barely know how to write and read to a file let alone delete a specific line and replace it.

Comment: Your error is telling you what is needed. Data types need to be the the same to compare. Look up how to convert either string to integer or integer to string. That should fix your issue.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I want. I'm looking for a basic structure on how to do this. I'm not looking for a vague answer that makes me go trying to search up how to do it to no avail.  That's the reason I'm on here in the first place.